# Spring Integration http outbound gateway POST response does not contain escaped ampersand

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-integration

The original POST response received contains XML like below having escaped ampersand `&amp;`

```
<Order>test&amp;test</Order>
```

But the Java application is receiving it as below where & is not escaped:

```
<Order>test&test</Order>
```

I would prefer to receive the original XML having escaped ampersand `&amp;` in the XML.

The Spring Integration configuration used to handle POST request response is below:

```
   <int:chain input-channel="requestChannel">
        <int-http:outbound-gateway url="http://example.com"
                                   http-method="POST"
                                   expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                                   request-factory="requestFactory"
                                   charset="UTF-8"                                   
    />
    </int:chain>

   <bean id="requestFactory"
         class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <property name="connectTimeout" value="10000"/>
        <property name="readTimeout"    value="10000"/>
    </bean>
```

I was wondering if I was missing anything in the above configurations. What can be the reason that `&amp;` is automatically converted to `&` in the payload that I extract from POST response.

The other interesting thing that I noticed is when if the server side is sending `&gt;` symbol Example `<Order>test&gt;test</Order>` I am receiving it as the same i.e.  `<Order>test&gt;test</Order>`; But if the server is sending back both `&gt;` and `&amp;` together example `<Order>test&gt;test&amp;test</Order>` I am receiving it as `<Order>test>test&test</Order>`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at a network trace, I think you'll find that is happening on the server side.

You might have to send `&amp;amp;`.

Comment: Hi Gary. I have looked into the network logs using wireshark and I could see that  &amp; is coming back from the server side. I also comfirmed the same from client as well.

Comment: I dont think server side should send &amp;amp;  If the server side is sending &gt; for > symbol then the application is reciving &gt; itself. I would have thought it should do the same for &amp; as well

Comment: Sorry - misread the question - I thought you said the outbound `&amp;` was received as `&` by the server. However, I just ran a test and it worked fine for me - trace `<Hello> from the other side &amp;</Hello>`, received `++++++++++++ Replied with: <Hello> from the other side &amp;</Hello> ++++++++++++`. What version of spring/spring integration are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.0.7.RELEASE for Spring-integration-http and spring-integration-ws version.

Comment: I Have looked further into network logs and found below in the HTTP POST response headers: 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1                                                     I was wondering whether it is it because of above charset that the ampersand &amp; gets decoded to & after going through spring integration ? Have you tested having above headers in your reply or is it using UTF-8 ?

Comment: I also cannot use expected-response-type="byte[]" in my int-http:outbound-gateway setting which would have preserved whatever the payload that I received. My application is such that I can only use expected-response-type="java.lang.String"  in my settings.

Comment: Just to reiterate about spring versions. I am using 3.0.7.RELEASE for Spring-integration-http and spring-integration-ws version. and am using 3.2.3.RELEASE for other spring.versions

Comment: Can you try with a more recent release? The current release is 4.3.1.